# How to add spaces between items in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I createad a Recyclerview like the image below.
How to manage that?

[image]

Comment: post some code and clarify your problem.

Comment: if you want to set spaces between your recycler view items then give margin to layout that you are inflating inside recyclerview.

Comment: where do u want space in recycler view? i cant figure out from the given image

Answer (score 6):

add this to the root layout of your singlerow.xml :

```
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

**Update**

> Vertical spacing ItemDecoration

Extend ItemDecoration, add custom constructor which takes space height as a parameter and override getItemOffsets() method:

```
public class VerticalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int verticalSpaceHeight;

    public VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(int verticalSpaceHeight) {
        this.verticalSpaceHeight = verticalSpaceHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
            RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.bottom = verticalSpaceHeight;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to insert space below the last item, add the following condition:

```
if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) != parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
            outRect.bottom = verticalSpaceHeight;
}
```

Note: you can also modify outRect.top, outRect.left and outRect.right properties for desired effect.

Comment: But first row display 6 item then second 5

Comment: @pragnesh please take a look to my answer I updated it

Comment: But how to manage first row has 6 column and second row has 5 column